# Is there a way to globally set android:theme to a specific view type?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Problem: I have all of my `EditText`s using `android:theme` on my XMLs because of the need to set `colorControlNormal` to transparent. I wish to set that custom per view theme globally.

Bear in mind that I'm not looking to change the ***style***, but the ***theme***. So something like overriding `editTextStyle` in my theme won't work because `colorControlNormal` is a theme attribute, it's not present in the style and thus can't be overridden.

I realize that I could extend `EditText` to do this, but that comes with its own complications, and I was wondering if there was an easier, more elegant way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's no theme counter part for `editTextStyle`. I think your best bet is to subclass `EditText` and apply the theme there.